# session is expiring prematurely on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I have set up [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#initializer-settings) for user authentication in ROR backend app. My client credentials are expiring prematurely(like 3,5 minutes) and i couldn't find the heck why it is so.

Devise config files

initializers/devise_token_auth.rb

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = true         
  config.token_lifespan = 24.hours      
  config.default_confirm_success_url = "http://localhost:4000"
end
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "support@xyz.com"
  config.navigational_formats = [:json]

end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base     
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2,:facebook] 
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

I confirmed expiry header set to after 24 hours after authenticating the user, but still they expire after 3-5 minutes and subsequent api calls give invalid credentials error.

Thanks

i

Comment: How are you saving your sessions? Cookie-based stores are easier to debug. Is the cookie expiring?

Comment: Try to change "change_headers_on_each_request" to false:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#about-token-management

or maybe you are not always using the latest token. I'm just guessing.